# Asterisk, Queue with AGI or macro

Tags: queue, asterisk, amazon-ami, agi

I need to put a caller to queue. And at this moment it is a basics - Queue command, but i have to check if this caller have permission to call an agent at this moment. I have running in background AMI script which setting up permissions.

So, is it possible to return a caller to queue if he dont have permission to make a call to agent ?

Comment: AGI may be better used here. Check using AGI what permission has caller and then route him accordingly. You can use AGI to set variable on channel and then check it in dialplan.

Comment: Esyscoder  dzieki za zainteresowanie. Thank you for your respond. You see i have to put caller to queue and there is no option for other logic for incoming calls. I have to check permission from queue. There is about 17 queues with this same agents for all queue. And if you know how works queues then you agree with me that is sucks. Because each queue will tried put caller to agent but i need send only first caller to agent from each queue. So i wrote script which is running backround and checking via AMI which queue has caller and if queue has then put to astdb value 1 either put 0.

Comment: AMI can do Redirect. So you can reroute caller already in queue. Mayby that helps.

Comment: How? Which commands can do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AMI command Redirect. You have to know caller channel but with AMI you probably track calls and their channels already (via Events).

```
pbx*CLI> manager show command Redirect
[Syntax] 
Action: Redirect
[ActionID:] <value>
Channel: <value>
[ExtraChannel:] <value>
Exten: <value>
[ExtraExten:] <value>
Context: <value>
[ExtraContext:] <value>
Priority: <value>
[ExtraPriority:] <value>

[Synopsis]
Redirect (transfer) a call. 

[Description]
Redirect (transfer) a call.

[Arguments]
ActionID
    ActionID for this transaction. Will be returned.
Channel
    Channel to redirect.
ExtraChannel
    Second call leg to transfer (optional).
Exten
    Extension to transfer to.
ExtraExten
    Extension to transfer extrachannel to (optional).
Context  
    Context to transfer to.
ExtraContext
    Context to transfer extrachannel to (optional).
Priority 
    Priority to transfer to.
ExtraPriority
    Priority to transfer extrachannel to (optional).

[See Also]
Not available

[Privilege]
call,all 

[List Responses]
None

[Final Response]
None
```

You need to specify `Channel` of the caller you want to redirect and destination for redirection with `Context`, `Exten`, `Priority`. Now you can redirect any caller to any other extension in dialplan.

We were using it like that for years until we switched to AGI approach.